# Load Multiple Image in single Row with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am Using UIL to load images with ListView
there is Two Images in Every Row And UIL Only Loads One Image And Other one not shows

```
        LTH.dLog(TAG, "User Name : " + getItem(position).getAgentName() + " " + getItem(position).getAgentFamily());
        LTH.dLog(TAG, "User Avatar : " + getItem(position).getAgentAvatar());
        LTH.dLog(TAG, "Insurance Avatar : " + getItem(position).getAgentInsuranceAvatar());
        LTH.dLog(TAG, "****************************************");

        imageLoaderInsurance = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        optionsInsurance = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                // .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer((int) 27.5f))
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.thumb_list)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.thumb_list)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.thumb_list)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap process(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                .build();

        imageLoaderInsurance.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(App.getContext()));
        imageLoaderInsurance.displayImage(getItem(position).getAgentInsuranceAvatar(), img_insurance_avatar, optionsInsurance);

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(App.getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.global_radius)))
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.profile_user)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.profile_user)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.profile_user)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();

        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(App.getContext()));
        imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getAgentAvatar(), img_agent_avatar, options);
```

Image's Links works well, and i have no idea why images not loading

`User Avatar` Load has Done, But `Insurance Avatar` Not Shows andallways is empty (`R.drawable.thumb_list` Not Shows even)

How i can fix it

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `postProcessor` or return bitmap in method, not null

Comment: Thanks dude, it was my `Fault`